# Accessing /etc/environment value in unix using python error?

Tags: python

I tried to set a new "System wide environment" variable and tried to access it using python. I put `'PRODUCTION_SERVER'=1` in etc/environment. After rebooting i tested it in python interpreter and it was successful

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ.get('PRODUCTION_SERVER')
'1'
>>>
```

But when i used the same line inside my flask project in that server it returned None.

```
import os
print os.environ.get('PRODUCTION_SERVER')
```

Output

```
None
```

Why am i getting different results in same system?

Comment: I used shell without sudo or anything. Can you suggest me a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this is the problem, but:

The /etc/environment file is only loaded when you log in (it is read by the `pam_env` PAM module).  If your flask service is running an an environment that was created before you changed the /etc/environment file, it would not see new values you have entered into that file.